# doFilter not getting called

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Could you help to check why doFilter not getting called

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
<filter-name>roseFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>net.paoding.rose.RoseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>roseFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

class signature:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
public class RoseFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
```

404 is returned while call http://localhost:8080/hello/world, I set the breakpoints at
  doFilter, it seems doFilter not called?(I tried tomcat 6.0.18, 6.0.29, jdk1.6)

Comment: Does `/hello/world` resolve into a resource for your server? If not, there is no reason to start a filter chain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've come across this myself before, with the `/*` pattern not working. I don't think I ever ever resolved it.

Comment: @rsp: the resource doesn't necessarily need to be a physical existing resource. The filter (and servlet) mapped on `/*` will be invoked anyway. It might namely act as a front controller.

Comment: @BalusC, is the filter chain started when no servlet or other non-filter resource is matched by the path? The web.xml only specifies a listener and a filter and nothing else.

Comment: @rsp: Certainly. Otherwise filter-based (MVC) frameworks like Spring (MVC) wouldn't ever have worked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The filter won't be invoked when:

1. The filter class is missing in the classpath and/or is not loadable or instantiable. You should however have noticed it in the server's startup logs. Solution is to be found based on the interpretation of the exceptions/errors found in the server logs.
2. There's another filter running before in the chain which isn't calling [`FilterChain#doFilter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), but rather [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) or [`include()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) which caused the subsequent filters in the chain being completely skipped (when they do not listen on `FORWARD` or `INCLUDE` dispatchers; they by default only listens on `REQUEST` dispatcher). Solution is either to fix the wrong filter, or to add `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` etc accordingly, or to rearrange the filter declarations in `web.xml` so that your new filter comes *before* the another filter (you in turn only need to ensure that your new filter is using the `FilterChain#doFilter()` properly :) ).
3. The request URL is plain wrong. You used http://localhost:8080/hello/world. With a filter listening on `/*`, this means that the webapp context should be ROOT or at least `/hello`. Verify your webapp context. I'd just retry with an URL which points to a valid JSP/Servlet inside the same webapp which generates a non-404 response. Does the filter then get called as well?

Comment: 1. Filter class is good since initFilterBean is called properly.

Comment: I check the destroy() API:This method is only called once all threads within the filter's doFilter method have exited or after a timeout period has passed. Maybe it is timeout?

Comment: I added a 3rd cause (which is after all pretty obvious, but you never know :) ).

Comment: I think so too BalusC. As I said in my response, his filter is probably set on the wrong URL.

Comment: @Coolbeans: your answer did however not explain it that way and is suggesting a bit odd solution.

Comment: I agree BalusC. My answer was not explained in details.

Comment: Thanks - I have the same issue adding <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> to filter-mapping solved my issue !

Comment: @BalusC Thanks a TON!!!!

Following helped me 

 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Name-Of-Your-Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: My problem is solved but the problem is the session. My session is not maintained what I can do for it

Answer (score 0):

What's the web request look like? Can you try changing your url-pattern to ***.jsp** instead of / * ? If you are using something other than pure JSP then change it to whatever the request ending extension is (like for struts it is usually *.do).