# Servlet Filter not being called

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have a filter setup to be called for all requests to a particular servlet (account servlet in my case). This is within the context of a Google App Engine Project. When the form is submitted, the request first goes to google, and they then do a POST to my servlet so that I can retrieve the uploaded blobs. The form action is:

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/account/submit-order")
```

My filter mapping is:

```xml
   <filter>
      <filter-name>Account Servlet Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.myapp.filters.AccountServletFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Account Servlet Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Account Servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
```

My servlet mapping is:

```xml
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Account Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.myapp.servlets.AccountActionServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Account Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/account/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

The filter works when I perform a GET request to an account URL within the app, but for some reason, the request coming in from google (as a POST) is not triggering the filter. Any ideas?

I have verified that if I POST the form to /account/foo (setting that as the action of the form, with method POST), the servlet filter is triggered, so the filter is working, but for some reason, when the POST request comes from google, the servlet is invoked directly, and the filter is bypassed.

Comment: Your problem is not in web.xml but probably in the code of either your servlet or your filter, Can you post those as well?

Comment: The servlet is being called, it's just that the filter is not being triggered, I have debugging turned on with a breakpoint.

Comment: I have no clue at this point.

Comment: maybe your problem is what @JoD. is mentioning in his/her answer, have you tried that?

Comment: There is one other filter that should get called before the account filter. I'm saying it should be called first because it is defined in web.xml before the filter for account is defined. I turned debugging on, and even that filter is not being called for the request from createUploadURL. If I change the form action to hit /account/foo directly, both filters are invoked. There is something weird about the way the servlets are being invoked by google after the blobs are uploaded. That's the only conclusion I can draw.

Answer (score 0):

Possible options

There is another filter that does not passes on to the next filter in the chain using [`chain.doFilter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain)).

[UPDATE]
Just found this [@BalusC post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660057/744133) for something similar - he has also a checklist of options. One is matching this, the other 2 do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution indicated in the referenced BalusC posting may prove effective. The Blobstore service employs RequestDispatcher.forward() in place of an HTTP request, when in dev mode. In the `<filter-mapping>` entry you could use `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>` or `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`.